# Symfony 4.1.6, A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object of class

Tags: symfony, symfony4, serialization

When serializing Entity which has relations to another entiyty.

`A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object of class` happens, if you don't set `setCircularReferenceLimit` and `setCircularReferenceHandler`.

It sloveed the problem before symfony3.2 but now Symofony4.1.6,`Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded` happens and timeout.

Where should I check????

```
$encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
$norm = new ObjectNormalizer();

//// it fixes the problem before Symfony 3.2, but no it causes timeout
$norm->setCircularReferenceLimit(0);
$norm->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
     return $object->getId();
});
//////////

$normalizers = array($norm);
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

/// get entity from doctorine2//
$myEntity = .... 

$jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($myEntity, 'json');
```

my Error is

```
in vendor/symfony/property-access/PropertyAccessor.php (line 372)

    $result = self::$resultProto;        
    $object = $zval[self::VALUE];        
    $access = $this->getReadAccessInfo(\get_class($object), $property); 

    if (self::ACCESS_TYPE_METHOD === $access[self::ACCESS_TYPE]) {            
    $result[self::VALUE] = $object->{$access[self::ACCESS_NAME]}();
    } elseif (self::ACCESS_TYPE_PROPERTY === $access[self::ACCESS_TYPE]) {            
        $result[self::VALUE] = $object->{$access[self::ACCESS_NAME]};


    if ($access[self::ACCESS_REF] && isset($zval[self::REF])) {                
    $result[self::REF] = &$object->{$access[self::ACCESS_NAME]};
```

Comment: You don't need to paste the snippet for the Property Accessor, but could you mabe show your object that you want to serialize? It's enough to show the circular bit. This will help us reproduce the issue and investigate the problem.

Comment: Hey, you made it?